# What does "agree on" mean in term of morphisms?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

> Let $k$ be a field. Consider the inclusion of $k[x, xy, xy^2 - y]$ into
>   $k[x,y]$. I claim that this is an epimorphism. Note that it is an
>   inclusion, no non-units become units, and $k[x,y]$ has no idempotents.
>
> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are two morphisms from $k[x,y]$ to some other
>   commutative ring which agree on the given subring. Using $f(xy)=g(xy)$
>   and $f(x)=g(x)$, we see that $f(xy^2)=g(xy^2)$:

What does it mean when we say $f$ and $g$ agree on the given subring?

Comment: It means that $f$ and $g$ have the same "output value" for the same "input value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f $ and $g $ agree on some subring means that for any element $x $ in the given subring, we have $f (x)=g (x). $